# Prove that if $F_n$ is highly abundant, then so is $n$.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, divisor-sum

Define $F_n$ to be the $n$th Fibonacci number, define $\sigma(n)$ to be the sum of the divisors of $n$, and call $n$ highly abundant if and only if $\sigma(n)>\sigma(m) \hspace{3mm} \forall m<n$.

Prove that if $F_q$ is highly abundant, then so is $q$ - analogous to the property that whenever $F_p$ is prime, $p$ is prime or $4$ - or find a counterexample.

The sequence of highly abundant Fibonacci numbers begins

$1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 144$

and the sequence of their indices begins

$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$

These are the only terms that I know of, but there may be others. Our search will be greatly aided by the fact that the Fibonacci numbers are a divisibility sequence - meaning that $F_a \mid F_b$ if and only if $a \mid b$ - if various things are true of the highly abundant numbers. I don't wish to make the proof of any of the following the point of this post, but information on highly abundant numbers seems to be *highly deficient*, so if upon further inspection I don't find recorded proofs or counterexamples and none are presented in the comments here, then I may make them the topic of a future question.

(1) - Every highly abundant number greater than $3$ is even

If true, then the index of every highly abundant Fibonacci number greater than $3$ must be divisible by $3$, since $F_3=2$.

(2) - Every highly abundant number greater than $16$ is divisible by $6$ or $10$

If true, then the index of every highly abundant Fibonacci number greater than $16$ is divisible by $12$ or $15$, since $F_{12}=144$ and $F_{15}=610$ are the smallest Fibonacci numbers that are divisible by $6$ and $10$ respectively.

**Update:** @Daniel Fischer has posted a proof below of (1) and the stronger statement than (2) that every highly abundant number greater than $20$ is divisible by $6$. (3) probably wouldn't give us a better restriction on the index than this without considerably more work outside the scope of this problem, but stronger statements such as $\forall k > 3024$ such that $k$ is highly abundant, $60 \mid k$, seem within reach, which, for example, would imply that any highly abundant Fibonacci number not in the list above (since I've checked every value below this limit) is divisible by $F(60)=1548008755920$, the first Fibonacci number divisible by $60$.

(3) - Every highly abundant number other than $3$ and $10$ is also practical (every smaller number can be represented as a sum of distinct divisors of the number)

If true, then the index of every highly abundant Fibonacci number greater than $10$ is divisible by $6$, since every practical number is divisible by $4$ or $6$, and $F_6=8$ and $F_{12}=144$ are the smallest Fibonacci numbers divisible by these two numbers respectively.

If any further values are found I'll add them to the sequences.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still working on the practicality, but here are proofs of (1) and a stronger form of (2):

We will often use the

**Lemma:** For all $m,\,n$, we have $\sigma(m)\cdot\sigma(n) \geqslant \sigma(m\cdot n)$ (with equality if and only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime).

**Proof:** We assume the coprime case known, so it remains to see that $\sigma(p^k)\sigma(p^r) > \sigma(p^{k+r})$ for $k,\,r > 0$. But

$$\begin{align}
(p-1)^2\left(\sigma(p^k)\sigma(p^r) - \sigma(p^{k+r})\right) &= (p^{k+1}-1)(p^{r+1}-1) - (p^{k+r+1}-1)(p-1)\\
&= p^{k+r+2}-p^{k+1}-p^{r+1}+1-p^{k+r+2}+p^{k+r+1}+p-1\\
&= p^{k+r+1}-p^{k+1}-p^{r+1}+p\\
&= p(p^k-1)(p^r-1)\\
&> 0.
\end{align}$$

Now we start investigating highly abundant numbers:

**Lemma:** Let $n > 3$ be an odd number. Then $n$ is not highly abundant.

**Proof:** Let $p > 3$ prime. Then $$\sigma(p-1) \geqslant (p-1) + \frac{p-1}{2} + 1 = p + \frac{p-1}{2} \geqslant p + 2 > p+1 = \sigma(p),$$ hence $p$ is not highly abundant.

Further, $$\sigma(p^2-1) \geqslant (p^2-1) + \frac{p^2-1}{2} + 2 + 1 = p^2 + \frac{p^2+1}{2} + 1 > p^2+p+1 = \sigma(p^2)$$ and hence $p^2$ is not abundant either.

Let $3 \leqslant p < q$ with distinct primes $p,q$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(pq-1) &\geqslant (pq-1) + \frac{pq-1}{2} + 2 + 1\\
&= pq + \frac{pq+1}{2} +1\\
&= pq+p+q+1 + \frac{pq-2p-2q+1}{2}\\
&= pq+p+q+1 + \frac{(p-2)(q-2)-3}{2}\\
&\geqslant pq+p+q+1 = \sigma(pq).
\end{align}$$

If $5 \mid n$, then $m = 4\frac{n}{5} < n$ and $\sigma(m) = 7\sigma(n/5) > 6\sigma(n/5) \geqslant \sigma(n)$, hence $n$ is not highly abundant. If $9\mid n$, then $m = 8\frac{n}{9} < n$ and $\sigma(m) = 15\sigma(n/9) > 13\sigma(n/9) \geqslant \sigma(n)$, so $n$ is not highly abundant.

So only numbers with at least two prime factors $\geqslant 7$ and at most one factor $3$ remain. Let $p > 5$ a prime dividing $n$. Let $2^a < p < 2^{a+1}$. If $p < 2^{a+1}-1$, then $m = 2^a\frac{n}{p} < n$ and $\sigma(m) = (2^{a+1}-1)\sigma(n/p) \geqslant (p+1)\sigma(n/p) \geqslant \sigma(n)$, so $n$ is not highly abundant. If $p = 2^{a+1}-1$, then $m = 2^{a-1}\cdot 3\cdot\frac{n}{p} < n$, and

$$\begin{align}
\sigma(m) &= (2^a-1)\cdot 4\cdot \sigma(n/p)\\
&= (2^{a+2}-4)\sigma(n/p)\\
&> 2^{a+1}\sigma(n/p)\\
&\geqslant (p+1)\sigma(n/p) \geqslant \sigma(n)
\end{align}$$

if $3\not\mid n$, and for $n = 3\cdot k$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sigma(m) &= (2^a-1)\cdot 13 \cdot \sigma(k/p)\\
&= (2^{a+3} + 5\cdot 2^a - 13)\sigma(k/p)\\
&\geqslant 2^{a+3}\sigma(k/p)\\
&= 4(p+1)\sigma(k/p)\\
&\geqslant \sigma(n).
\end{align}$$

By similar methods we prove the next

**Lemma:** Let $n > 20$ be highly abundant. Then $n \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$.

**Proof:** First we note that $2^k$ is highly abundant if and only if
$k \leqslant 4$. For if $k \geqslant 5$, then $\sigma(2^{k-4}\cdot 15) = (2^{k-3}-1)\cdot 24 = 3\cdot 2^k - 24 = (2^{k+1}-1) + 2^k-23 > \sigma(2^k)$.

So let $n = 2^k\cdot m > 20$ with $k\geqslant 1$, odd $m > 1$, and
$m \not\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. We show that $n$ is not highly abundant.

Now if $n$ has a prime factor $p > 5$, let $3^a < p < 3^{a+1}$. Since $p$ and $3^{a+1}$ are both odd, we have $3^{a+1}-1 \geqslant p+1$. If $p/3 < 3^a < p/2$, then

$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^{k+1}3^am/p) &= (2^{k+2}-1)\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\sigma(m/p)\\
&> (2^{k+1}-1)(p+1)\sigma(m/p)\\
&\geqslant \sigma(2^km) = \sigma(n).
\end{align}$$
If $3^a = \frac{p+1}{2}$, then $a \geqslant 2$, $p \geqslant 17$, $3^{a-1}5n/p < n$ and
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(3^{a-1}5n/p) &\geqslant \frac{3^a-1}{2}\cdot 5\cdot\sigma(n/p)\\
&= 5\frac{p-1}{4}\sigma(n/p)\\
&\geqslant (p+1)\sigma(n/p) \geqslant \sigma(n).
\end{align}$$

If $(p+1)/2 < 3^a < 3p/4$, then $a \geqslant 2$, and
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^{k+2}3^{a-1}m/p) &= (2^{k+3}-1)\frac{3^a-1}{2}\sigma(m/p)\\
&\geqslant (2^{k+3}-1)\frac{p+1}{4}\sigma(m/p)\\
&> (2^{k+1}-1)(p+1)\sigma(m/p)\\
&\geqslant (2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(m) = \sigma(n).
\end{align}$$

If $\frac{3p}{4} < 3^a < p$, then $p \geqslant 11$ and
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(3^an/p) &= \frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\sigma(n/p)\\
&\geqslant \frac{9p-1}{8}\sigma(n/p)\\
&> (p+1)\sigma(n/p) \geqslant \sigma(n).
\end{align}$$

So the case $n = 2^k\cdot 5^m$ remains. If $m \geqslant 2$, then
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^{k+3}\cdot 3\cdot 5^{m-2}) &= (2^{k+4}-1)\cdot 4 \cdot \sigma(5^{m-2})\\
&= \left(32(2^{k+1}-1) + 28\right)\sigma(5^{m-2})\\
&> (2^{k+1}-1)31\sigma(5^{m-2}) \geqslant \sigma(2^k5^m).
\end{align}$$

Finally, for $n = 2^k\cdot 5$ with $k \geqslant 3$, we have
$$\sigma(2^{k-1}\cdot 3^2)-\sigma(2^k\cdot 5) = 13(2^k-1) - 6(2^{k+1}-1) = 2^k - 7 > 0,$$

and the proof is complete.

Next we will prove the

**Lemma:** If $n > 630$ is highly abundant, then $n \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$.

**Proof:** We already know that $n$ is not highly abundant if $n \not\equiv 0 \pmod{6}$, so let $n \equiv 6 \pmod{12}$. Let $n = 2\cdot 3^a\cdot m$, with $\gcd(m,6) = 1$. We have, for $a \geqslant 2$,

$$\begin{align}
31\cdot \frac{3^{a-1}-1}{2} &> 3\cdot\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\\
\iff 31\cdot 3^{a-1} - 31 &> 27\cdot 3^{a-1} - 3\\
\iff 4\cdot 3^{a-1} &> 28\\
\iff 3^{a-1} &> 7,
\end{align}$$

so if $a \geqslant 3$, then $n$ is not highly abundant, since $\sigma(2^4\cdot 3^{a-2}m) > \sigma(2\cdot 3^am)$, hence in the following we assume $a \in \lbrace 1,\, 2\rbrace$.

If $5^2 \mid m$, then

$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^43^{a+1}m/5^2) &= 31\frac{3^{a+2}-1}{2}\sigma(m/5^2)\\
&> 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\cdot 31\sigma(m/5^2)\\
&\geqslant 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\sigma(m) = \sigma(2\cdot 3^am) = \sigma(n),
\end{align}$$
so $n$ is not highly abundant. If $7^2 \mid m$, then
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^53^{a+1}m/7^2) &= 63\frac{3^{a+2}-1}{2}\sigma(m/7^2)\\
&> 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\cdot 63\sigma(m/7^2)\\
&> 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\cdot 57\sigma(m/7^2)\\
&\geqslant 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\sigma(m) = \sigma(n),
\end{align}$$
so $n$ is not highly abundant.

It remains to show that if $n$ has a prime divisor $p > 7$, then $n$ is not highly abundant, where we can assume that neither $5^2$ nor $7^2$ divides $n$.

Let $2^c < p < 2^{c+1}$. If $2^c > \frac{3p+4}{4}$, then

$$\sigma(2p) = 3(p+1) \leqslant 2^{c+2}-1 = \sigma(2^{c+1}),$$ hence $\sigma(n) \leqslant \sigma(2^cn/p)$, and $n$ is not highly abundant.

If $\frac{2p}{3} < 2^c \leqslant \frac{3p+4}{4}$, and $p > 15$, then $2^{c-2}\cdot 5 < p$ and writing $m = 5^b\cdot r$ with $r \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^{c-1}5^{b+1}) - \sigma(2\cdot5^bp) &= (2^c-1)\frac{5^{b+2}-1}{4} - 3\frac{5^{b+1}-1}{4}(p+1)\\
&\geqslant \frac{2p-1}{3}\cdot\frac{5^{b+2}-1}{4} - 3\frac{5^{b+1}-1}{4}p - 3\frac{5^{b+1}-1}{4}\\
&= \left(\frac{2(5^{b+2}-1)}{12} -\frac{9(5^{b+1}-1)}{12}\right)p\\
&\qquad - \left(\frac{9(5^{b+1}-1)}{12}+\frac{5^{b+2}-1}{12}\right)\\
&= \frac{5^{b+1}+7}{12}p - \frac{14\cdot 5^{b+1}-10}{12} > 0,
\end{align}$$
hence $\sigma(n) \leqslant \sigma(2^{c-2}5n/p)$, and $n$ is not highly abundant.

If $\frac{p}{2} < 2^c < \frac{2p}{3}$, and $2^{c+1}-1 \geqslant p+1$, we have

$$\sigma(2^c\cdot 3^{a+1}) = (2^{c+1}-1)\frac{3^{a+2}-1}{2} > (p+1)\cdot 3 \frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2} = \sigma(2\cdot3^ap),$$
and if $2^{c+1}-1 = p$, then
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(2^c\cdot 3^{a+1}) -\sigma(2\cdot3^ap) &= (2^{c+1}-1)\frac{3^{a+2}-1}{2} - 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}(p+1)\\
&= p - 3\frac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}\\
&\geqslant p - 39.
\end{align}$$

The remaining cases are $p = 31$, when $\sigma(30n/31) > \sigma(n)$ is easily verified, and $p = 11$, when $\sigma(10n/11) > \sigma(n)$ because $n$ is not divisile by $5^2$.

The maximal highly abundant number $\equiv 6 \pmod{12}$ is hence $2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 630$.

Comment: Thanks for working all this out. I believe the general statement holds that $\forall k \in \Bbb Z^+ \hspace{1mm} \exists A; \hspace{1mm} k|a(n) \hspace{2mm} \forall a(n)>A$, where $a(n)$ is the $n$th highly abundant number and $A$ is highly abundant. This is based on [the first 10,000 values](http://oeis.org/A002093/b002093.txt), from which it appears that when $k=5,10,20,30,$ or $ 60, A=3024$. $10$ and $30$ would follow from your lemmas and proof of the case $k=5$, while $20$ and $60$ follow by also proving that for $k=4,A=630$. Can your proof be adapted for larger primes and prime powers?

Comment: I think it can be shown in pretty much the same way that all highly abundant numbers larger than $630$ are divisible by $12$, and all larger than 3024 divisible by $5$. It gets messier for each prime factor you add, of course, and I don't think it would be feasible to prove the general statement that for each $k$ all large enough highly abundant numbers are multiples of $k$ in that way (if that is true, which I'm not sure about). I don't have much time today, but I'll look about $12$ and $5$ tomorrow.

Comment: Likely pairs $(k,A)$ for some small powers of primes are $(8,540540)$,$(16,1164544781400)$,$(9,8168160)$,$(27,31672512601329600)$,$(25,1226737062541710720)$,$(7,47520)$,$(11,46781280)$,$(13,37067738400)$,$(17,23016885091200)$,$(19,761980038019200)$. Supposing that $k=16,9,5,7,11,$ and $13$ are all correct, any further highly abundant Fibonacci numbers must be divisible by $F_{840}$ since these $A$ are less than $F(60)$ and $840$ is the least common multiple of the indices of the smallest Fibonacci numbers divisible by their respective $k$.

Comment: I've added the proof that all highly abundant numbers $> 630$ are divisible by $4$ (hence by $12$). Working on the others, well, at least some. Not sure how far I'm willing to go.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, therefore I put this comment into an answer.
'whenever Fp is prime, so is p' should be 'if $F_p$ is prime, then $p$ is prime or $4$'.